# Notation for inhabited sets

Tags: notation, set-theory, topos-theory, constructive-mathematics

A set $X$ is called [inhabited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inhabited_set) if it has some element. In classical mathematics, this means that it is not the empty set (i.e. it does *not not* have an element), so that one usually writes $X \neq \emptyset$. However, in [intuitionistic mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic), being inhabited is a stronger condition (in fact, the more natural one). Has any (short) notation been used for this relation "being inhabited" in the literature? I suggest $X \geq 1$, but I am not really happy about that either.

Comment: In choiceless set theory sometimes we write $A\preceq B$ to say there exists an injection from $A$ into $B$. I suppose that from an intuitionistic point of view, it would mean that there really is such function. And so if $A=1=\{0\}$, such function will tell you exactly what sort of element inhabits $B$.

Comment: Personally, I have never seen a special notation. Some people abuse notation and write "nonempty" and "$X \neq \emptyset$" when in fact they mean the constructively stronger condition. Interpreting $X$ as an element of $\mathcal{P}(X)$, one could also write $\diamond X$, where "$\diamond$" is standard notation for the unique [positivity predicate](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/positive+element) on $\mathcal{P}(X)$.

Comment: Isn't this $\exists x. x \in X$? Or are you looking for something shorter? Is $|X| > 0$ intuitionistically equivalent?

Comment: Sure this is $\exists x. x \in X$, but I wonder if there is a good (and common) shortcut for this formula. Apparently, not.